# Select first in and last out time - different date from data finger

Tags: sql

I would like get help in the following Attendance Data, each exit and entry log stores a different row for an employee id.

```
ID  |  Name  |  Code           |  Date        |  Time
--------------------------------------------------------
1      Jhon     IN                2021-07-01     7:00
1      Jhon     OUT               2021-07-01     15:00
2      Roy      IN                2021-07-01     7:00
3      Yuki     OUT               2021-07-01     15:00
4      Mike     IN                2021-07-01     16:00
4      Mike     IN                2021-07-01     16:10
4      Mike     OUT               2021-07-02     1:00
4      Mike     IN                2021-07-02     9:00
4      Mike     OUT               2021-07-02     19:00
5      Andrew   IN                2021-07-01     16:00
5      Andrew   IN                2021-07-02     9:00
5      Andrew   OUT               2021-07-02     19:00
5      Andrew   OUT               2021-07-02     19:10
6      Tiara    OUT               2021-07-02     1:00
6      Tiara    IN                2021-07-02     9:00
6      Tiara    OUT               2021-07-02     19:00
7      Bob      IN                2021-07-01     16:00
7      Bob      IN                2021-07-02     9:00
7      Bob      OUT               2021-07-02     19:00
```

Conditions

1. Assume Employees will be IN and OUT in same day/next day.
2. Assume There will be multiple IN and OUT for same day/next day for employees. So need first IN and Last Out.
3. Duration = (FirstInTime - LastOutTime)

**=====I want this result======**

```
ID  | DateIN      | ScanIN  | DateOUT     | ScanOUT  | Duration
1     2021-07-01    7:00      2021-07-01    15:00      8.00
2     2021-07-01    7:00      NULL          NULL       NULL
3     NULL          NULL      2021-07-01    15:00      NULL
4     2021-07-01    16:00     2021-07-02    1:00       9.00
4     2021-07-02    9:00      2021-07-02    19:00      10.00
5     2021-07-01    16:00     NULL          NULL       NULL
5     2021-07-02    9:00      2021-07-02    19:10      10.10
6     NULL          NULL      2021-07-02    1:00       NULL
6     2021-07-02    9:00      2021-07-02    19:00      10.00
7     2021-07-01    16:00     NULL          NULL       NULL
7     2021-07-02    9:00      2021-07-02    19:00      10.00
```

How to achieve this? With the condition FIRST IN AND LAST OUT.
Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I don't see how your results match your explanation.  You explicitly say that you want the min time in and max time out on each day.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you seem to want aggregation.  The basic idea is:

```
select id, date as datein, min(time) as timein,
       date as dateout, max(time) as timeout,
       (max(time) - min(time)) as duration
from t
group by id, date;
```

Date and time functions are notoriously database-dependent, so the difference calculation may use specific functions for whatever database you are using.